# Does Implicit upcasting happen in Visual C#?

Tags: c#

`double b = 1.5 * a`, where `a` is a `float` variable.

Will `a` be casted to `double` before performing multiplication in Visual C# on Visual Studio 2010??

Answer (score 8):

The float will be converted to a `double` **before** multiplication, if that is what you mean.

```
float a = 1.2F;
double b = 1.5*a;
```

Gives:

```
L_0000: nop <========== just because I'm in debug mode
L_0001: ldc.r4 1.2 <=== load the float value 1.2
L_0006: stloc.0 <====== store in "a"
L_0007: ldc.r8 1.5 <=== load the double value 1.5
L_0010: ldloc.0 <====== load "a"
L_0011: conv.r8 <====== widen the value we obtained from "a" to become a double
L_0012: mul <========== multiply as double
L_0013: stloc.1 <====== store in "b"
L_0014: ret <========== all done
```

Note this only changes the **copy** of the value from `a` on the stack; `a` itself remains unaffected.

Comment: L_006 stores in `a` or in `b` ? Stores in `a` I think.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Will 1.5 be converted to double if the type of "b" variable is float?? How will the expression evaluated if the type of "b" is float??

Comment: @Mahesh you'd need to add a `(float)` for it to compile. The multiplication would be exactly the same; you would just get an extra `conv.r4` between `mul` and `stloc.1`, changing the **result** of the double multiplication to a float

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Does this evaluation of the above expression remain the same in Visual C++ 6.0??

Comment: @Mahesh you'd have to ask a C++ person that.

Answer (score 0):

As per rules, There are no change in Type of 'a', In this case it will remain float.
Result of the expression will be evaluated as double implicitly, But the value of 'a' will double before evaluation as you consider.

in following case it will cast to Double before evaluation.

```
double b = 1.5 * (double)a ;
```

Comment: It casts a to `double` *whether or not* you add the `(double)`.